# ScrollView inside fragment not scrolling

Tags: android, scrollview

In my Activity I have a `FrameLayout`, that suppose to use as container for fragments.

In my fragment I got a `ScrollView` that doesn't respond. `ScrollView` contains `TextView` set `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`, with text from my java code that clearly longer than the size of the `ScrollView`.

My fragment xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="@dimen/bookview.imageWidth"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:id="@+id/bookView.image"/>
        <TextView
            android:textSize="@dimen/custom_book_text"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/bookView.image"
            android:id="@+id/bookView.name"/>
        <TextView
            android:textSize="@dimen/custom_book_text"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/bookView.image"
            android:layout_below="@id/bookView.name"
            android:id="@+id/bookView.author"/>
        <TextView
            android:textSize="@dimen/custom_book_text"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/bookView.image"
            android:layout_below="@id/bookView.author"
            android:id="@+id/bookView.pages"/>
        <TextView
            android:textSize="@dimen/custom_book_text"

            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/bookView.image"
            android:layout_below="@id/bookView.pages"
            android:id="@+id/bookView.category"/>
        <TextView
            android:textSize="@dimen/custom_book_text"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/bookView.image"
            android:layout_below="@id/bookView.category"
            android:id="@+id/bookView.publishingDate"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="end">
        <TextView
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:textSize="@dimen/custom_book_text"
            android:id="@+id/bookView.description"/>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

the xml of the activity:

```
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/use.drawer">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/user_custom_book_height"
            android:id="@+id/user.customBookContainer"/>
        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/user.container"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <include
        layout="@layout/navigation_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

---

i use FrameLayout because i want to change the fragment in that area,in runtime.better idea? i like to hear.

i have tried to decrese the heigth of the ScrollView.
my fragment java code:

```
public class BookView extends Fragment {

    private Bitmap bitmap;
    private String name;

    public static BookView newInstance(String book,Bitmap bitmap) {

        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        BookView fragment = new BookView();
        fragment.bitmap = bitmap;
        fragment.name = book;
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public BookView() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_book_view, container, true);
        Backend backend = BackendFactory.getInstance();
        try {
            Book b = backend.readBook(name);
            TextView textView = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.bookView_name);
            textView.setText(b.getBookName());
            textView = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.bookView_author);
            textView.setText(b.getAuthor());
            textView = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.bookView_category);
            textView.setText(b.getCategory().name());
            textView = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.bookView_description);
            textView.setText(b.getDescription());
            textView = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.bookView_pages);
            textView.setText(Integer.toString(b.getPages()));
            textView = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.bookView_publishingDate);
            textView.setText(b.getPublishingDate());
            final ImageView imageView = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.bookView_image);
            if(bitmap != null){
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            } else{
                ImageLoader imageLoader = new ImageLoader();
                imageLoader.setListener(new ImageLoader.ImageTaskListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onActionEnd() {}

                    @Override
                    public void onImageDownload(Bitmap bitmap) {
                        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    }
                });
                imageLoader.execute(b.getImage());
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
            builder.setMessage(e.getMessage());
            builder.create().show();
        }

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_book_view, container, false);
    }
}
```

imageLoader is a class i wrote,it extened AsyncTask for download image from a url and update the UI when it ready.

Comment: why are you using framelayout for fragments, any particular reason?

Comment: can you post your code, screenshot would be better ?

Comment: try using linear layout or relative instead of framelayout.

Comment: your text clearly either not long enough or your above scrollview widgets taking more space so its not visible in UI. check again or post your screenshot@user4349397

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are able to see the fragment's view.

If so a few things to try:

Set the scroll view to fillViewPort="true" 
and then set the text view to match parent since this is the only view in the scroll view. As a note you should really avoid using hard coded widths & heights (even dp heights).

Instead of returning

```
return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_book_view, container, false);
```

just return the original view: v

Nother' bit of readability: instead of reassigning textview each time. 
do:

```
((TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.blabla)).setText("BLA");
```

**Edit:**

I have tested this & it works.

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:fillViewport="true">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/faq_output_answer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Can you see the text in the textview (thats inside of the scrollview)? Also try the edit.

Comment: i checked your code,still the same reaction,i see grey scroller at the side when i touch the ScrollView but i doesn't scroll.so i kow he fire the event and that it should scroll because the grey scroller is smaller when i can't see the whole text.

Answer (score 0):

I think other parts (TextViews and ImageViews) of this fragment full all area of screen and ScrollView render out of screen.
I suggest you put all layout inside ScrollView.
like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="end">

<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/bookView.image"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/bookview.imageWidth"
                android:layout_height="250dp"/>

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/bookView.name"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@id/bookView.image"
                android:textSize="@dimen/custom_book_text"/>

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/bookView.author"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/bookView.name"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@id/bookView.image"
                android:textSize="@dimen/custom_book_text"/>

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/bookView.pages"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/bookView.author"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@id/bookView.image"
                android:textSize="@dimen/custom_book_text"/>

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/bookView.category"

                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/bookView.pages"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@id/bookView.image"
                android:textSize="@dimen/custom_book_text"/>

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/bookView.publishingDate"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/bookView.category"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@id/bookView.image"
                android:textSize="@dimen/custom_book_text"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/bookView.description"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="@dimen/custom_book_text"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: i want only the description TextView to scroll all other thing has to be static

Comment: Size of other part is full screen. In small screen you can`'t handle this!

Comment: This is a big trouble in small screen!! You must select one of this strategy:
-Use two ScrollView to handle top part and bottom part. This two ScrollView fill all screen area.
-Use my suggestion above

Answer (score 0):

Try putting an empty view as the last item in your scrollview.

```
<View 
android:layout_width = "match_parent"
android:layout_height = "50dp" />
```

This worked for me.